# Android Custom view = Out of Memory

Tags: android, view, android-customview, outofmemoryerror

Проблема следующая имеется приложение, в одной из Активити которого есть customView. При частой смене ориентации при активной активити с view или при смене активити туда-сюда - получается Out of memory.

Так же в Android Monitor видно, что через 3 минуты сборщик мусора иногда все же "соизволит" память очистить, но иногда и нет... и 9 переключений между этой и другой активити (туда-сюда) приводят к крешу приложения.

Причем вся графика на канвасе рисуется, картинки не используются. Это мое первое приложение на Андроид.. и возможно не хватает какого-нибудь метода, который убивает все объекты на моем View и его вызова в onDestroy.

Comment: может и не хватает, но мы не знаем, потому что код видите только вы.

Comment: Activity довольно большой объект, поэтому когда Вы между ними переключаетесь - а Вы добавляете в стек новую каждый раз, правильно? У Вас заполняется RAM, которая выделяется под приложение. Постарайтесь следить за тем, чтобы в данный момент как можно меньше крупных объектов было в памяти, не оставляйте статических ссылок на них (очень частая ошибка). GC кстати вызывается тогда, когда заполнение памяти близко к критичному и только для объектов у которых нет живых ссылок - уверены, что все ссылки на Ваши activity мертвы?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем решение найдено, оно скорее всего какое-то "быдлятцкое" и надо было искать почему же возникает этот "Memory Leak", но все решилось крайне просто:

Когда мы переходим в другую активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
```

Это чудо код очищает память полностью.

Проблема так же была при смене ориентации, она ушла после создания метода отключающего поток перерисовки в элементе view.

```
     public void DestroyView()
    {
        removeCallbacks(animator);
    }



    private Runnable animator = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean needNewFrame = false;
            long now = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
            for (Dynamics dynamics : datapoints)
            {
                dynamics.update(now);
                if (!dynamics.isAtRest()) {
                    needNewFrame = true;
                }
            }

            for (Dynamics dynamics : devicespoints)
            {
                dynamics.update(now);
                if (!dynamics.isAtRest()) {
                    needNewFrame = true;
                }
            }




            if (needNewFrame) {
                postDelayed(this, 15);
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    };

}
```